# Difference between two cells in third cell

Tags: vba, excel, difference

I was trying to make a VBA script that would calculate the differene between two cells and place it in the third cell. It should work in the following situation:

1. Three cells are selected. Two of them have values, the third one is blank.
2. The VBA script is run.
3. The VBA script calculates the difference between cells with values.
4. The difference is recorded in the third (blank) cell.

As you could understand such a VBA script should be able to record the difference in a cell on the right from the values, below, on the left or above.

I'm a newbie in vba so my vba coding depends a lot on the forums were similar issues are discussed. But this time I could not find a solution.

Comment: Do you ALWAYS want to subtract the smaller number from the larger number? Or the top left most value with the bottom right most value? or the opposite of either of those situations? As these difference can have a MAJOR impact on the final results. Or do you just want the Absolute difference? (either number subtracted and the solution always a positive difference of the numbers)? Do you want an error message when the selection is ***NOT*** 3 cells, 1 of which is empty?

Comment: If more than 3 cells are selected would you like the macro to continue and put the value in the top left or bottom right most empty cell, using the difference from the 2 top left or bottom right most cells?

Comment: It would be best if the macro could calculate the difference between the "corner" cell and the "middle" cell. Like here: 
Selection from the left to the right [100(corner), 20(middle), blank(corner)] -> 100 - 20 = 80 not 20 - 100 = -80.
Also it would be great if the formula was saved. The answer of L42 works good, but the result is saved as value.
Another good thing would be the ability to work in not continuous ranges. For example in the first selection are the values to calculate the difference between (100, 20) and the second selection is the blank cell where the difference is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

Set rng = Selection

If rng.Cells.Count <> 3 Then Exit Sub

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    If .CountA(rng) <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    For Each cel In rng
        If cel.Value = "" Then
            Select Case True
            Case cel.Address = rng(1).Address
                cel.Value = rng(2)-rng(3)
            Case cel.Address = rng(2).Address
                cel.Value = rng(1)-rng(3)
            Case cel.Address = rng(3).Address
                cel.Value = rng(1)-rng(2)
            End Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With
```

not tested soi leave it to you.
**Edited for simoco**

Comment: L42, `Difference between two cells in third cell`, not sum:)

Comment: @simoco haha sorry, my bad. I must be dozing off a bit. :)