# Difference between two cells

Tags: excel-formula

I intend to find difference between two cells use excel formula only.

Values in two cells are separated by comma. However, there is no space near the comma.

Assume in B2, the value is

```
apple pie,fish,cheese
```

And in B3, the value is

```
apple pie,cheese,fish,vegetables,banana
```

I have to get vegetables,banana in E2

I am thinking about use EXACT function

```
=exact(B2,B3)
```

However the result returns FALSE with no doubt as those values in two cells are not match exactly.

I also think to use MATCH function but the result is #N/A.

```
=MATCH(B2,B3,0)
```

For the result, what I need is to get

```
vegetables,banana
```

Is it possible to achieve this? Grateful for your advice please. Thank you.

Reference

[Find the difference between two cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688178/find-the-difference-between-two-cells)

[Difference between two cells in third cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799728/difference-between-two-cells-in-third-cell)

---

I am sorry I made mistakes in my first version in this post, I expect the result is

```
vegetables,banana
```

If in javascript, (I just use as example to show what I try to do in the excel)

I can use something like this

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(x) {
return this.filter(function(y) {return x.indexOf(y) < 0;});
};

//to get the result
[apple pie,cheese,fish,vegetables,banana].diff([apple pie,fish,cheese])
//the result will return
vegetables,banana
```

So I would like to know is it possible to use excel formula to do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not clear what you want - are you looking for the items that are the same in both locations? As the answer you provide has terms that are in both locations as well as some that are in only one...

Comment: Yeah, how is that result being achieved, did you mean the expected result is: `apple pie,cheese,fish`?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of items that you would find in a list? Without that, I don't believe that what you want is possible, as Excel does not provide a way to loop through a single cell.  (I'd love to be proven wrong about this!)

Comment: @SolarMike, I am sorry that I made mistakes in my post, the expected result should return `vegetables,banana`. I updated the post, please feel free to have a look and grateful for your advice. Thank you.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor, I am sorry that I made mistakes in my post, the expected result should return `vegetables,banana`. I updated the post, please feel free to have a look and grateful for your advice. Thank you.

Comment: @Choirbean, I am sorry that I made mistakes in my post, the expected result should return `vegetables,banana`. I updated the post, please feel free to have a look and grateful for your advice. Thank you.

Comment: More information in case it is useful: items in cell B2 and B3 are generated by another application, usually cell B2 has more items than cell B3. I intend to use excel formula because once I get items from B2 and B3, I can use the formula in E2 to show the result , after that I save it and import to another software. Unfortunately, the software does not adapt the excel that contains macros or vba, so I try to use formula get the result. Also, if excel formula can return the result, I will start to think about how to sort the result.

Comment: As the order is not consistent I don't think it will be possible in a single cell. Can I use multiple cells with a formula dragged across?

Comment: Not a complete answer, however it may trigger something, but this finds the word or text up to the first comma in B2 and checks to see if it exists in B3, returns a 1 as apple pie is there. I had thought of using an if() statement, but trying to get 2 or more words returned has not come to me ... FIND(TRIM(MID(B2,1,FIND(",",B2,1)-1)),B3,1)